# RabbitMq Build in Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I am confused that some people build the docker image with rabbitmq service only .

https://x-team.com/blog/set-up-rabbitmq-with-docker-compose/

And Some build the rabbitmq service in the docker ubuntu

https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/master/3.8/ubuntu/Dockerfile

I am confused that what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your second link point to the docker file used to create a rabbit image  from scratch. The,image can then be built with docker build and distributed for use.

The first link on the other hand is actually just using a pre-built image of rabbit. It is not building it from scratch.

It is just like building a binary from source code vs just running the binary.

Comment: Thats means i can put the first link image to the aws container and connect to another container?

Comment: And what is the difference of usage of this two?

Comment: You could use the image in aws Ecs, or any other container orchestration tool like Kubernetes if you wanted too. However I would suggest you read up on basic docker and docker compose documentation first and play with docker locally on your machine before making the jump to running containers in the cloud

Comment: Because i am locally use the php-fpm image in docker container, nginx server  in docker container, and mysql in docker container ,  Therefore , i want to build rabbitmq also. I am confused that what is the different in usage in these case?

Comment: My advice is to always use the existing official image, unless you have a specific requirement to rebuild the image from scratch (which is very rare)